# Trigger click not activating data-toggle

Tags: jquery

I have the following button

`<a class="btn-email" data-parent="#booking" data-target="#body-four" href="#body-four" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="body-four">Call Back</a>`

When the user clicks the button it calls the following jQuery function

```
$("a.btn-email").click( function() {
    var result = false;
    if (!$("a.btn-email").hasClass('opening')) {
        if ($("#body-four").hasClass('collapse') && !$("#body-four").hasClass('in')) {
           var result = true;

            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               async: true,
               url: "validate.php",
               data: $("#bookingForm").serialize(),
               success: function(data) {
                   var message = $.parseJSON(data);
                   if(message['status']=='failed') {
                     ....
                   } else {
                    $("a.btn-email").attr("data-toggle", "collapse");
                    $("a.btn-email").addClass('opening');
                    $("a.btn-email").trigger('click');
                  }
               }
            })
            $("#dlgError").dialog("destroy");
        }
    } else {
        $("a.btn-email").removeClass('opening');
        $("a.btn-email").removeAttr('data-toggle');
    }
});
```

If the ajax validation is successful then the function adds the data-toggle attribute to the button and then simulates the click so that the data-toggle will open the bootstrap accordion, but the triggle('click') doesn't activate the data-toggle, I have to manually click the button again to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Move your logic into separate functions to be called by JQuery. So you can call them, instead of triggering an event.

Comment: The reason I need to trigger a click is because it's using an accordion and the only way to get that to work is to actually click it as I have no idea what the function is that runs the accordion as I did not build the site

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the `else` part:

```
....

else {
       $("a.btn-email").attr("data-toggle", "collapse");
       $("a.btn-email").addClass('opening'); 
       var href = $("a.btn-email").attr("href");// get the href   
       $(href).collapse("toggle");
     }

.....
```

Comment: I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).collapse is not a function"